# Writing word backwards

Tags: python, indexing, reverse

I know there are possibilities :

> sampleword[::-1]

or

```
reverse(string)
```

but I wanted to write it by myself. I don't get why my code doesn't work. Could you help me?

```
h=input('word\n\n');
rev(h)
def rev(h):
    counter=len(h);
    reverse="";
    while counter>0:
        reverse+=h[counter];
        counter=counter-1;
    return reverse
    #print (reverse); ?
input();
```

Comment: always define 'does not work'

Comment: Hint: Index starts at 0.

Comment: does not work - NameError: name 'rev' is not defined

Comment: Put the `h=input` and `rev(h)` below the function declaration. It doesn't know what `rev` is because when you reference it, the function is not defined.

Comment: yeah i came up with counter=len(h) - 1 but didn't know that last part. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple issues with your code, I pointed them out in the comments of this adjusted script:

```
def rev(h):
    counter=len(h) - 1 # indexes of h go from 0 to len(h) - 1
    reverse=""
    while counter>=0: # changed to >=0
        reverse+=h[counter]
        counter -= 1
    return reverse

h=input('word\n\n');
revers = rev(h) # put rev(h) after the definition of rev!
print(revers) # actually print the result
# deleted your last line
```

In addition, you don't need to terminate lines with `;` in python and you can write `counter=counter-1` as `counter -= 1`.

Answer (score 2):

You have some issues/problems in your code.

1. You call `rev()` before it is defined
2. Indexing starts at `0`, so you need `>= 0` instead of `> 0`
3. You want `counter` to equal `len(h) - 1` because again, indexing starts at `0`
4. You do not need semicolons at the end of your lines

Here is a much simpler and faster way using recursion:

```
def reverse(text):
    if len(text) <= 1:
        return text
    return reverse(text[1:]) + text[0]
```

Comment: Thanks :) Still as I said I know there are possibilities :
sampleword[::-1]
or
reverse(string) 
but I wanted to write it by myself

Comment: @Greg This is redefining `reverse` as a user defined recursive function and not using the builtin, he is writing it himself

Comment: @MikeRixWolfe yes, this does not use the built-in `reverse()`, it creates a new function of the same name.

Comment: Yep, was just clarifying it on your behalf, as Greg didn't seem to understand

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I wasn't looking carefully enough. That's why built in functions shouldn't be named same as defined by user imo

Answer (score 0):

As you use Python more you will come across the concept of "Pythonic" code ... code that uses Python features well and shows good programming style.

So, you have a good answer above showing how your code can be corrected to work correctly in Python.   But the issue I want to point out is that's C style programming.  Someone said you can write C in any language (especially true in C++ and C#), but if you do you are probably not using the features of the language well.  In Python, writing this style of function and ignoring the available built-in, implemented in C, lightning fast methods is not Pythonic.

I guarantee you that reverse(string) or string[::-1] are both faster than your rev( ) python code. Python has a ton of built in functionality and extensive library of files you can import for extra already debugged functionality. See if you can find a good way to time the execution of reverse( string ) and your rev( ) function. There is a good way, in Python.

Comment: The OP wants to write a string-reverse function by himself as an exercise, he knows there are fast built-ins.